# Unable to login into oracle DB

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I have installed oracle 11g DB in windows 7 64 bit.
During installation it asked for a password to global database orcl(default one). I gave a password and finished the setup.

Later, I tried to log in from command prompt with "sqlplus / as sysdba". It is scolding as insufficient privileges.

```
 C:\Users\krishna prasad>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Jun 1 16:11:14 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


Enter user-name:
```

I installed the db with user krishna prasad only. how to set the user to dba group or any other way to enter DB. Thanks in advance.

Also I tried with command prompt as administrator

```
C:\Windows\system32>id
uid=1000(krishna prasad) gid=513(None) groups=513(None),0(root),544(Administrato
rs),545(Users)

C:\Windows\system32>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Jun 1 16:35:32 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


Enter user-name:
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

```
  1. type sqlplus then press enter
  2. it will ask for username. type this /as sysdba
```

Answer (score 1):

open command prompt and type this
start SQL*Plus /as sysdba
i think this will help you